Estimate of Harmonic function
Let $f$ be harmonic function in $ \mathbb{R} \times ( 0 ,\infty)$. That is $ \Delta f = 0 $ in this domain. Then is the following true?
$$
\frac{1}{r} \int_{r/2}^{r} \vert f(x,t) \vert dt \leq C \vert f(x,r) \vert.
$$
Where $ x $ is fixed and $ r > 0 $. $C$ here has to be independent of $ r,f $, and $ x $. I prove this with extra assumption that $ f \geq 0 $ but I need this for any harmonic $ f $.
Any ideas are appreciated.

I think this is not true: Consider the harmonic function $f(x,y)=e^x\cos(y)$. Then the inequality would read
$$
\frac{1}{r}\int_{r/2}^re^x|\cos(t)|dt \le Ce^x|\cos(r)| ~~~ (r>0)\iff \frac{1}{r}\int_{r/2}^r|\cos(t)|dt \le C|\cos(r)| ~~~ (r>0) ,
$$
which is impossible since
$$
\frac{1}{r}\int_{r/2}^r|\cos(t)|dt  > 0 \quad (r>0).
$$
